# Binding property to control in Winforms

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, binding

What is the best way to bind a property to a control so that when the property value is changed, the control's bound property changes with it.

So if I have a property `FirstName` which I want to bind to a textbox's `txtFirstName` text value. So if I change `FirstName` to value "Stack" then the property `txtFirstName.Text` also changes to value "Stack".

I know this may sound a stupid question but I'll appreciate the help.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` And add binding to textbox.

I will provide C# code snippet. Hope it helps

```
class Sample : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set
        {
            firstName = value;
            InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FirstName"));
        }
    }

    #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void InvokePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Usage :

```
 Sample sourceObject = new Sample();
 textbox.DataBindings.Add("Text",sourceObject,"FirstName");
 sourceObject.FirstName = "Stack";
```

Comment: the post is tagged winforms - is this not for wpf?

Comment: This will update `sourceObject` when `textBox.Text` changes.  You also need to subscribe to the `PropertyChanged` event to update the text box contents when `sourceObject.FirstName` changes (which was the original question).

Comment: thanks... just a quick question, would this work as two-way binding? when I change the textbox text property, would the firstname property change as well?

Comment: @David - this is working two ways. Just created app and tested it

Comment: @Stecya - OK, sorry (I remember having to do both but that was some time ago).

Comment: @Stecya This is not entirely correct. Given the above example, it will work when I change `sourceObject.FirstName` and it will work when I change the text in the textbox in the UI and leave the textbox. However, when I update the text of the textbox in code-behind by doing `textbox.Text = "Anything"` it will not update the property in the `sourceObject`. So I think the binding update gets triggered by the .NET on the internal leave event of any control, it's not? Please correct me, when I'm wrong. For me this case is not enough to go with.

Comment: To bind changes in control to the property, use this
`textbox.DataBindings.Add("Text",sourceObject,"FirstName", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);`

Comment: That's nice. Though I suggest using method that automatically gets property name for your convenience: `        protected void OnPropertyChanged()
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(new System.Diagnostics.StackFrame(1).GetMethod().Name.Replace("set_", "")));
        }`

Comment: +1: A note I was not aware of but is obvious after the fact: this will not work with properties not marked as `public`. It will throw a binding error regarding the dataMember.

Answer (score 13):

A **simplified version of the accepted answer** that does NOT require you to type names of properties manually in every property setter like `OnPropertyChanged("some-property-name")`. Instead you just call `OnPropertyChanged()` without parameters:

> You need .NET 4.5 minimum.
>   `CallerMemberName` is in the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` namespace

```
public class Sample : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _propString;
    private int _propInt;


    //======================================
    // Actual implementation
    //======================================
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    //======================================
    // END: actual implementation
    //======================================


    public string PropString
    {
        get { return _propString; }
        set
        {
            // do not trigger change event if values are the same
            if (Equals(value, _propString)) return;
            _propString = value;

            //===================
            // Usage in the Source
            //===================
            OnPropertyChanged();

        }
    }

    public int PropInt
    {
        get { return _propInt; }
        set
        {
            // do not allow negative numbers, but always trigger a change event
            _propInt = value < 0 ? 0 : value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage stays the same:

```
var source = new Sample();
textbox.DataBindings.Add("Text", source, "PropString");
source.PropString = "Some new string";
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I'm getting na error on "CallerMemberName". Does it has to be deffined in some place?

Comment: You need .NET 4.5 minimum. [CallerMemberName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute) is in the System.Runtime.CompilerServices namespace

Comment: [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator] does not exists even when using .net 4.6.1 and System.Runtime.CompilerServices namespace.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23213146/what-is-notifypropertychangedinvocator-in-c-sharp-when-implements-inotifyprope