# How to bind a variable to a control's text property in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, binding

I'm not sure if this is possible and my google-fu is not very strong with this one. If I have some `int` variable count and some `Label`, is it possible to bind them together so that if the variable changes then the label reflects that change?

I suppose if I made the variable a property in the set portion I could update the label.. but then again I have quite a bit of variables I'd like to do this to and I rather not have a bunch of private properties used only for that.

I'd also like to stay away from events/delegates. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: WinForms, WebForms, MVC, WPF or Silverlight?

Comment: Did you take a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883282/binding-property-to-control-in-winforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

updating a label is not a complex task. so just manually update the label when you change the variable value.