# What is [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator] in C# when implements INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1, c#-5.0

I see two types of implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`

- The first one:

  ```
  public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
      {
          PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
          if (handler != null)
          {
              handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- The second one:

  ```
  public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
      protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
      {
          PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
          if (handler != null)
          {
              handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
          }
      }
  }
  ```

In 2nd one you see there is an extra attribute `[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]` on the method `OnPropertyChanged`

In my case both behaves same but what, why and when to use this `[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]`, what are benefits of this? I've searched on internet but couldn't find any good answer.

Answer (score 93):

It is a Resharper attribute from their [Annotations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__Code_Annotations.html) - designed to give you warning then your code looks suspicious :) 
Consider this:

```
public class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
     
     [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
     protected virtual void NotifyChanged(string propertyName) { ... }
  
     private string _name;
     public string Name {
       get { return _name; }
       set { 
             _name = value; 
             NotifyChanged("LastName");//<-- warning here
           } 
     }
   }
```

With the `[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]` attribute on the `NotifyChanged` method **Resharper will give you a warning**, that you are invoking the method with a (presumably) wrong value.

Because Resharper now knows *that* method should be called to make change notification, it will help you convert normal properties into properties with change notification:
[image: Visual Studio Screenshot showing ReShaper suggestions]

Converting it into this:

```
public string Name
{
  get { return _name; }
  set
  {
    if (value == _name) return;
    _name = value;
    NotifyChange("Name");
  }
}
```

This example is from the documentation on the `[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]` attribute found here:
[image]

Comment: Plus 1 for the explanation, and not just answering with a link. This should be selected as the answer.

Comment: I do not understand.. What warning is given, why, when, what for? Is this normal it changed from "LastName" to "Name"? I'm confused. (Also link is dead now - and the page isn't on archive.org)

Comment: @JeromeJ I have updated the link. The warning is something resharper does (underlining the code with "zigzag" blue color). For more info on _why_ the above property is problematic - search for `INotifyPropertyChanged` and examples of how it is usually implemented

Comment: If you have multiple methods having this tag, ReSharper will list them in the contextmenu and let you pick the one you want to auto-implement. (eg one using `string` or one using `Expression<Func<T>>` )

Answer (score 5):

The `NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator` is a [Resharper](http://www.spikie.be/blog/post/2013/07/02/Making-Resharper-and-MVVM-Lights-ViewModelBase-play-nice.aspx) feature.

You can simply remove it from your code in order for it to work

Similar question been asked here:

[does anyone know how to get the [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5c000063-517a-4193-b7f7-29dadd7cbd4b/c-wpf-app-does-anyone-know-how-to-get-the-notifypropertychangedinvocator-statement-to-work?forum=wpf)

Comment: Is is a C# Feature. Resharper is just an Tool, and not able to add any extra code which c# is not Supported. There is also some thing behind NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator.

Comment: Then You say [CallerMemberName] is also added by Resharper, By removing the Code is also working, But CallMemberName resolve a headache of giving name or properties where we call it. Same i want to know about NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator

Check it here

http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2012/07/whats-new-in-c-50-learn-about.html

Comment: @WaqasIdrees CallMemberName is a feature of C# with .net 4.5.Allows you to obtain the method or property name of the caller to the method. Can you prove NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator comes with C#? since you have downvoted

Comment: But as you says that NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator is a Resharper feature that's why i down voted. It is a c# Feature. But what is the benefits of this and when to use. Why Resharper adding this.

Comment: @WaqasIdrees can you post the link or documentation for NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator to prove it comes with C#

Comment: +0, -1 For [plagiarizing](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5c000063-517a-4193-b7f7-29dadd7cbd4b/c-wpf-app-does-anyone-know-how-to-get-the-notifypropertychangedinvocator-statement-to-work?forum=wpf)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I have posted the link with the answer

Comment: That is not the link which I provided, Your link is also a plagiarized!

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Should i remove the answer?

Comment: Not necessarily, Just give the credit to the original answer.

Comment: @WaqasIdrees - `INotifyPropertyChanged` is defined in a .NET library (it's not C# language feature). `NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator` is a ReSharper feature. [Search for "NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator" on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator) and you'll find that there is no documentation for it, only links to forums and Stackoverflow.

Comment: Simply stating that you can remove `NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator` from your code 'in order for it to work' doesn't come close to answering this question.