# Bind a Class property to controls Winform - C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

There is a question [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883282/binding-property-to-control-in-winforms) to this but it is possible to make it in a reverse process.

To bind a property to a control so that when the `control` value is changed, the **class bound property** changes with it.

Example:

I have a class `Person` with `Firstname` property that is bound to a textbox `txtFn` control when the `txtFn` text value changes the class `Person.Firstname` property changes with it.

> UPDATE

The referred question still answer two-way binding. It is in their comments below.

Comment: If you read your refered question, in the comments explain how to make it a two-way binding

Comment: oh yeah, but i thought the answer will only solve 1-way binding but it is already working two-way binding i failed to see the comments below.