# how read multiple text box in C#

Tags: c#

i have about twenty text box in visual C# which their name are text box1,textbox2 and.... .

User inserts number in each text box and i want to read these numbers and save them in array like a[].

I  tried this code but it took  long time to do for all array component

`a[0]=Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);`

Is there any way which i use "for" loop that computer read automatically read text box and save the number in a[] array in order?

thank you

Comment: something like this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883282/binding-property-to-control-in-winforms where you bind the textbox to a backing property instead (ie, an array of strings).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding property to control in Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883282/binding-property-to-control-in-winforms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [use the Controls collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt340bh4.aspx). Here is a simple example:

```
for (int i=0; i<= a.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    var name = string.Format("textBox{0}", i+1);
    var textbox = this.Controls[name] as TextBox;
    a[i] = textbox.Text;
}
```